# Hover action moves the text. How do I fix it?

Tags: css

As the title says, I'm having issues with the hover action. Not sure what's causing it.

---

```
body {
    font-family: -apple-system-system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont, "Gurmukhi MN Regular";
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Global */
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Header */
header{
    background: #3e3e3e;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
    min-height: 50px;
}

header a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 21.73px;
}

header ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 140px 0 140px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .current a{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    padding: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}

header li a:hover{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    padding: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

---

I'm working on my first website for my portfolio. I've done all the markup for the first page and I've started styling it, but I'm stuck on the navigation bar. It's only the hover action that isn't working as I want it to. I'm trying to make it so that there's a rounded box behind it in a darker shade than the navigation bar, but the hover effect moves the text to the right a little bit. I read somewhere that it could be padding but I'm not entirely sure.

Appreciate any help, I'm new to all this.

Alex

Comment: Share your HTML also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag  in the default state doesn't have the same values of padding and font-size of when it's on hover.

Try correct your code like this:

```
header a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 8px;
    height: 5px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using **header a** for simple action and **header li a** for hovering kindly try to replace your code with the following, If there is any question feel free to ask, if it solves your problem , then vote up to acknowledge our combine effort.
Thank You.
Best Wishes,

```
    body {
    font-family: -apple-system-system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont, "Gurmukhi MN Regular";
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Global */
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Header */

    header{
        background: #3e3e3e;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 15px;
        min-height: 50px;
    }

    header a{
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 21.73px;
    }
     header  a:hover{
        font-size: 21px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: #2d2d2d;
        padding: 8px;
        height: 5px;
    }

    header ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    header li{
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 140px 0 140px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-right: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    header .current a{
        font-size: 21px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: #2d2d2d;
        padding: 8px;
        height: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: Can i get more details , mean it's really useful. But what about the a:hover property